# Any good alternatives to TortoiseSVN?

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

I am working with large ASP.NET websites and TortoiseSVN is just causing too many problems when files or folders are moved, renamed, or deleted. It keeps locking the repo and no matter how many times you run a cleanup it wants those missing files committed, or renamed.

There just isn't time to sit there and manually issue all those commands. Does anyone have a good alternative to TortoiseSVN?

Comment: This could be a workflow issue; are people doing SVN renames, deletes, etc. on the repos?

Comment: I am sorry, you are doing something wrong. TortoiseSVN is amongst the best GUI clients for SVN, probably on any platform. I would recommend you to look up proper way of doing moves etc. and then doing them. Personally, I do moves, renames a lot, and I don't get issue like you mention.

Comment: I aggree, you need to use the Rename, Delete options from Tortoise not from the Explorer. I suggest [this](http://tortoisesvn.net/usefultips.html) link list, there you find some usefull tips, and also a feature to repair these renames/moves where you just used the explorer, instead of svn.

Comment: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All folders contain hidden `.svn` folders. When you move them, yes, there may be problems. If you only use **TortoiseSVN context menu** to move stuff, you won't have these problems.

If you prefer to move folders from the IDE, use [AnkhSVN](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/), which is an awesome **Visual Studio extension** that integrates TortoiseSVN-like options into Solution Explorer window and tracks changes made in the IDE.

Finally, if you're not satisfied with how Subversion handles moves, renames and merges, you may want to look into **more modern version control systems**. [Git](http://git-scm.com/) is fantastic but takes some effort to learn and AFAIK doesn't have a good support on Windows. [Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/) may just what you need, as it's easier than Git and has a better Windows support.

Both Git and Mercurial use a **single directory** at the root of your project to store their data so **you will never corrupt a working copy** by moving folders and files around.

Check out [Joel Splosky's guide to Mercurial](http://hginit.com/) and [differences between Mercurial and Subversion](http://www.pixelastic.com/blog/265%3adifferences-mercurial-subversion).

Comment: If the workflow is not proper / things are done without proper understanding, things can happen on any VCS. SVN's move, rename handling is pretty good, though not to the level of Git / Hg. IMO, TSVN is very user friendly and there is limited avenues for messing it up. Git /Hg, have a steep learning curve and frankly, I can mess up Git, Hg etc if I do wrong things. I would not suggest move to Git / Mercurial in this context.

Comment: Problem is everything here is such a rush job that time it takes to manually move stuff via tortoise slows you down too much

Answer (score 1):

[VisualSVN](http://www.visualsvn.com/visualsvn/) integrates with Visual Studio to automate file renames/deletes, ignore lists, etc.